# How could I lock a directory?

Tags: perl, locking, directory, rotation

I'm making backups with `rsnapshot`. The path to the backups looks like this:

```
name=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
/backup/hourly.0/"$name"
```

In a perl script I choose from the the different snapshots to make `diffs` to the files in my home directory.

```
my $backup = '/backup';

opendir my $dh, $backup or die $!;
my @versions;
while ( defined( my $version = readdir $dh ) ) {
    # ...
    push @versions, $version;
}
# choose from @versions
# do something with the choosen
```

Is there a way to lock the backup directory, so that `rsnapshot` doesn't begin to rotate the snapshots while I am running my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot lock a directory with an exclusive lock because exclusive locks require that the file be opened for reading and writing, and directories cannot be opened for reading & writing. You could lock a file instead, but remember that file locks are advisory. So if `rsnapshot` does not also lock the directory then you are locking it and nobody else is paying attention to your lock and it doesn't accomplish anything.

Some options:

- Create a lock file inside the directory and lock it exclusively in your script. Also have the script that invokes `rsnapshot` lock it.
- Use a naming scheme that suffixes filenames with a timestamp instead of `.0`, `.1`, etc... so that you don't need to rotate them.
- Make your scanning script robust against directories that disappear while it is scanning. If a directory disappears, ignore it or restart the scan.